# Elasticsearch spring data - dynamic indexName in document annotation

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, repository, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible avoid the indexName in document annotation? Because I have dynamic indexName so I cannot define it previously

Comment: Leaving aside Spring and its template, what actually do you want to achieve at Elasticsearch side? What does `update any of those dynamically created indices with info to Elasticsearch` mean?

Comment: I use the ElasticsearchTemplate to create indices dynamically. I have a model which contains the Document annotation and I want to use it to update info using different indices, so I need to modify the indexName dynamically of the model to that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-93) and [the related PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/56), you can use a SpEL expression in the `indexName` attribute of the `@Document` annotation:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@somePrefix}-index", type = "sometype")
```

where you also have a bean like the one below defined in your context

```
<bean id="somePrefix" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${env}-myapp"/>
</bean>
```

So in your case, you could have a bean which contains a mutable index name that is then used to create/search the new indices.

Comment: So how can I modify the bean value from a Java method?

Comment: May the bright mind who downvoted care to explain why so all the community benefits from his wisdom ;-)

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada You probably should show some code so we better see what you're willing to achieve

Comment: Yo @Val I have created a new question, because this one is not mine so I couldn't paste my own code.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578688/update-index-dynamically-doesnt-work-spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: yup. My final degree project depends on this, so I am taking this problem so serious, thanks!