# Update index dynamically doesn't work (Spring Data Elasticsearch)

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, indexing, dynamic, spring-data

I have a model which is:

```
@Document(indexName = "index", type = "logs")
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String test_no;
    private String entire_log;
    private String method;
    private String timestamp;
    private String thread_name;
    private String level;
    private String logger_name;
    private String formatted_message;

    // CONSTRUCTORS, GETTERS AND SETTERS...
}
```

I have an `applicationContext.xml` file which contains a bean, used to save the value of the dynamic index. The location of this file is inside of `src/main/resources` directory, the same location than `application.properties` file. The bean is:

```
<bean id="index" class="elastest.loganalyzer.es.client.model.Index">
    <property name="v" value="defaut"></property>
</bean>
```

where the Index class is a simple class which contains a param "v":

```
public class Index {

    String v;

    public Index() {
        this.v = "default";
    }

    public String getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(String v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

}
```

What I want to do is to make the index of the above model (Log) dynamic. I have tried it by different ways but I can't find the correct solution:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{index}", type = "logs")
@Document(indexName = "#{index.v}", type = "logs")
@Document(indexName = "#{index.getV()}", type = "logs")
```

So... How can I make it works?

Comment: Have you tried this ? `"#{'${index.v}'}"`

Comment: @Val I did, and elasticsearch creates an index called ${index.v}, and It doesn't contain the value that I give it.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada any luck with this.  I am on the same boat as you here.  In my particular case I am trying to dynamically apply the index name from a field in the documents(pojo bean) that is tagged with the `@Document`

Comment: I didn't resolve the problem. I abandoned the spring methods and came back to the old method....

Comment: Which is the old method, @Grancein ? I didn't resolve this problem yet...

Comment: Did you resolve this problem yet ?

Comment: any update on this? i am stuck with same problem